# how to override action edit devise registration_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

how to override devise registrations_controller.rb for change templete?

i have code like this in my registrations_controller.rb :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
layout :defined_layout        
  def edit
    super        
    render :template => "registrations/edit2"
  end

end
```

my root :

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "user_sessions", :registrations => "registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" },
    :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',  :registration => 'register' }
```

i wont to change templete for edit my account in devise?
tell me how to do that?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to override controller. You can override edit view by by creating following file:

views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb